# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Oracle Instant Client - C++ linking error

Tags: c++, oracle, ubuntu-14.04, instantclient, ubuntu-16.04

I'm not sure if the problem is more suitable for **StackOverflow** or **AskUbuntu**, but I will ask.
I have two virtual machines. On one Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the other Ubuntu 16.04 LST. On both installed Oracle Instant Client 12.1 in the following way:

```
arkadiuszg@ubuntu:~/install/oracle$ ls -1
oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm

arkadiuszg@ubuntu:~/install/oracle$ sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient12.1-*

arkadiuszg@ubuntu:~/install/oracle$ cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d/

arkadiuszg@ubuntu:/etc/ld.so.conf.d$ sudo touch oracle-instantclient12.1.conf

arkadiuszg@ubuntu:/etc/ld.so.conf.d$ sudo vi oracle-instantclient12.1.conf
```

In created file I type:

```
/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib
```

And finally:

```
arkadiuszg@ubuntu:/etc/ld.so.conf.d$ sudo ldconfig
```

I am using C++ tools like: g++, make, gdb. Compiling the project runs on both machines correctly, but the problem is linking on **Ubuntu 16.04**. I keep getting the following errors:

```
DbConnection.cpp:(.text+0x536): undefined reference to `oracle::occi::Date::toText(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
build/Release/GNU-Linux/database/DbConnection.o: In function `CDbConnection::connect()':
DbConnection.cpp:(.text+0x1314): undefined reference to `oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, oracle::occi::Environment::Mode, void*, void* (*)(void*, unsigned long), void* (*)(void*, void*, unsigned long), void (*)(void*, void*))'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I do exactly this same on Ubuntu 14.04, then everything is OK. Compiling and linking ends with success.

Can anybody help me, please...

Comment: I already found a simple solution, just added to a `preprocessor directive`:
`-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the compiler version.
oracle occi is compatible with gcc 4.8.2
check the compiler version to see the differences